# Permission denied to access object when trying to call Greasemonkey-4 injected function

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

I want to add debug function to the page that allows me to click N times given element as one liner JS console call. I have following short script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Click given button N times
// @version  1
// ==/UserScript==


console.log("allright im here");
unsafeWindow.clickMe=function(target,n){

  if(!n){
     n=10;
  }
  for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
     target.click();
  }
}

unsafeWindow.test="blelbleb";
console.log(unsafeWindow.clickMe);
```

but when I try to to invoke that from the page (console) i get this

[image]

Why is that? How can I access exported function?

Moreover, `clickMe` is printed out as `Restricted`

[image]

How to deal with that ?

Comment: When using GM4, you must use the techniques of the duplicate question whether or not `@grant` values are set (when using `unsafeWindow`).  Also, `clickMe(null, 10);` would give an error regardless. ... Finally, you should include your GM and browser versions in questions like this.

Comment: But 1) I have no `@grant` here so `@grant none` 2)does not matter 3) I could include versions indeed.

Comment: Nevertheless duplicate answers my issue. I tried exportFunction but in form of `Components.something.exportFunction` but hit the wall since that `something` was undefined for some reasons. Thanks!